# Showing error messages in Qt / QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a class with a function which may or may not fail at certain points. It should yield an error message that can be shown to the user and return false upon failure.
This is what I've got:

```
class MyManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MyManager(QObject* parent);

    bool createSomething() {
        if(foo == false) {
            qDebug() << "foo can't be false here";
            //Error message should be shown to user
            return false;
        }
        //Do stuff
    }
```

The C++ side should be agnostic of the implementation in QML. One possible way to do it would be to have an `error(const QString& msg)` signal, like so:

```
bool createSomething() {
    if(foo == false) {
        qDebug() << "foo can't be false here"
        emit error("Foo is false");
        return false;
    }
    //Do stuff
}
```

and have to QML display it like so:

```
Connection {
    target: manager
    onError: errorMessageText.text = msg
}
```

One could also be more specific and have a signal called `creationError(const QString& msg)`

This whole implementation just feels wrong, and I'm sure there's a better way to do it architecturally. I'd be happy with some insights and ideas on this!

Comment: Do you want to only show the error message in qml?

Comment: @Nejat Yes, the entire UI is in QML. The user fills in a TextField, which 'text' property gets passed to the 'create' function. If it fails, I'm thinking it should just show an error message that tells the user why it failed.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your suggested approach, Using signal/slot mechanism is pretty nice to communicate between c++ and qml.

Comment: @Nejat Okay, cool. I just want to make sure I'm not shooting my leg of or anything. This class will be expanded with more functions and properties. So basically I was just wondering if I should have a more central error handling system.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is not so bad.

Anyway, You can do this also by eg. setting the property directly from C++ with `QObject::setProperty()`  or by invoking a QML method that changes it for you via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` but you will have to store (or find each time) the QML object you want to operate on.